# Как мне менять динамически толщину линии Python turtle

Tags: python, turtle

Как можно менять динамически ширину пера? Например с изменением цвета, цвет пера разный. Ума не приложу как это сделать...

 С пером разобрался, окей. Теперь не могу разобраться, почему программа закрывается после обрабатывания

```
import turtle

window = turtle.Screen()
window.title("Ковер-звездочка")
turtleTest = turtle.Turtle()
colors = ["orange", "green", "red", "blue"]  # составляем список цветов
turtleTest.speed(0.1)

def star(x, y, length, angle):
    turtleTest.penup()
    turtleTest.goto(x, y)
    turtleTest.pendown()
    turtleTest.begin_fill()
    while True:
        for x in range(4):
          turtleTest.color(colors[x % 4])
          turtleTest.forward(length)
          turtleTest.left(angle)
        if turtleTest.heading() < 1:
            break
    turtleTest.end_fill()

star(-360, 0, 750, 178)
```

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, нужно добавить `trurtle.penSize()`